# Altair 5 python visualitzation problem filters and interactivity

Tags: python, altair

I have the following code:

```py
# the code to read the data is 

collisions_data = pd.read_csv('example_path.csv')
collisions_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(collisions_data['DATE'], format='%Y-%d-%m')

geomap = geopandas.read_file('example_path.geojson')

weather_data = pd.read_csv('example_path.csv')
weather_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(weather_data['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# merge collisions and weather (this is done as i will need this later) (naming is due to other charts i have in other sections)

merged_data = pd.merge(collisions_data, weather_data, on='DATE')

# the code to make the plots is

select_month = alt.selection_point(fields = ['MONTH'], nearest = True)

brush = alt.selection_point(encodings = ['x','y'], fields = ['CRASH HOUR'],nearest = True)

color_month = alt.condition(
    select_month,
    alt.Color('MONTH:N').legend(None),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

color_month_and_brush = alt.condition(
    select_month & brush,
    alt.Color('MONTH:N').legend(None),
    alt.value('lightgray')
)

legend2 = alt.Chart(merged_data).mark_point().encode(
    alt.Y('MONTH:N'),
    color = color_month
).add_params(select_month)

barchart2 = alt.Chart(merged_data).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('CRASH HOUR:O'),
    y=alt.Y('count():Q'),
    color = color_month_and_brush
).transform_filter(select_month).add_params(brush)

points2 = alt.Chart(merged_data).mark_circle(size=17).encode(
    longitude = 'LONGITUDE:Q',
    latitude = 'LATITUDE:Q',
    opacity = alt.condition(select_month & brush,alt.value(1),alt.value(0))
).properties(
    width=650,
    height=450
)

background2 = alt.Chart(geomap).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).project('identity', reflectY=True).properties(
    width=650,
    height=450
)


scatter2 = alt.layer(background2,points2)
bars2 = alt.hconcat(barchart2,legend2)
chart = alt.hconcat(scatter2,bars2)

chart
```

The files contain in order: a dataframe of collisions, with the date of the accident (hour,day,month), a geojson with a map of NY, and a dataframe with weather information.

I thought the chart was working fine until i noticed that the bars in the barchart are not filtered once i interact with an element of the visualitzation, and acutally, none of the filters work in any of the charts. After playing for a bit i noticed that this only happened once i added the background2 to the visualitzation (any palce, with or without independent interactions, with or without the scatterplot on top). I am quite confused from this behaviour, and i have no idea why this happens (the rest works fine it is only the transform_filters that stop working).

Comment: Could you create a [mre] for this with the minimum amount of code and example data to reproduce?